# How to add final iteration to while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a function that runs a while loop:

```
void run_while_loop(const float x_d, const float x_max) 
{
    float x = 0;
    while ( x < x_max ){
        // do something
        x += x_d;
    }
}
```

It is assumed that x_d < x_max.

I want to change the function so that it adds an iteration at the end with x = x_max. If the function were called as:

```
run_while_loop(1, 3.123)
```

then I want the while loop to iterate for x = 0, 1, 2, 3, and 3.123.

What is an elegant way to code this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: In what cases should this iteration run? When `x_max * 2` can be represented as `[digits].0`?

Comment: @ForceBru All cases, x_max*2 does not have to be an integer.

Comment: Not directly related but if you assume x_d < x_max, I suggest you to assert it, just to prevent misuse ...

Comment: @fievel absolutely, I'm just trying to focus on the question and keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the code that is inside the while loop into a function, and call that function after the while-loop.

```
void run_while_loop(const float x_d, const float x_max) 
{
    float x = 0;
    while ( x < x_max ){
        do_something_function(parameters...);
        x += x_d;
    }
    do_something_function(final_parameters...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I had done (although I didn't wrap everything in the while loop into one function). I was thinking there might be a more elegant solution that deals with x.